# How to maintain the page state in Domino Web Application

Tags: javascript, ajax, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I am working on a Web Application developed & hosted on Domino R9 Server (Non Xpages Web Application). Each form has WebQueryOpen and WebQuerySave events implemented for the server side business logic. Problem is that on every page, when the page refreshes from the browser, application's home page/form is loaded. I want to maintain the state of a page in this application. 
Moreover, is there any possibility of implementing an Ajax based session handling (backend) in case the page was idle for sometime and session expired. For example if a user was writing something in the Web Editor (implemented in CKEditor latest version) and if his session is automatically dropped he should be able to start with least hassle and his already written stuff may not be lost.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to not use WebQueryOpen and WebQuerySave. Instead write the application to use modern web technologies (Ajax, JSON, REST API), then you don't need to save and reopen the page all the time. Doing that will give you everything you want.

I would build the page using standard HTML and Javascript (or even jQuery), then make Ajax calls to agents on the server to read/write data.

I have given several presentations on exactly this, with plenty of code samples and even finished code to download:
http://blog.texasswede.com/mwlug-2015/
http://blog.texasswede.com/my-mwlug-presentation-2/
http://blog.texasswede.com/my-connect-2017-demo-code/

Comment: I totally agree with you but the problem is that it's a huge application custom built in older versions of Lotus Domino i.e. Domino 7.0. I have incorporated some latest features in that but, you know, there is a limit of changing the business logic. WebQueryOpen & Save are implemented on all of the pages of the application and inevitably I have to get through them to achieve anything new. My current challenge is page state persistence and AJAX based calls.

Comment: For the session handling, why not write a function that updates a temporary document in the backend, through an Ajax call?  
This is how I would do it:  
Write a Javascript function where you read the values of all fields and pass it to the backend together with the UNID of the document. Call this function every 2 minutes (or whatever you think is appropriate) using setInterval().  (continued)

Comment: (continued)   
On the server you write a script that creates a temporary document (use a different form name than the normal form) and put all the values in it.
When the document is saved, you use clearInterval() to stop the updates, and also delete the temporary document on the server (using another Ajax call to the same script, this time with a special payload that will cause it to delete the temporary document.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the contents from all fields and CKEditor in a JSON string and also the UNID (or any "primary key") to the current entity (=page).

Afterwards, you can send this string to the server using AJAX, or as an alternative...

... have you tried using HTML5 local storage? See this page:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
Tell us how do you continue!!!

Comment: That's really a very good idea. I can store the DocUNID in the browser storage along-with the text written in "CKEditor" and post it to the server using AJAX. How can I use it for page state persistence? Especially when "WebQueryOpen/Save" is implemented on all of the pages. Also what about if, with help of AJAX I am posting the data to the server and user's session is over, how can I handle that? Does Domino provide the flexibility of creating the session through code?

Comment: I think that Notes can't create the session through code. In the server, in WebQueryOpen/Save, you can save and retrieve the information in a normal document, in the same Notes database or other database or even in a relational database. If the session ends, when user enters again and opens any form in the web application, you can recover the information and send in the page, for instance, as a Javascript variable in the HTMLHeader of the form. I still haven't used HTML5 local storage, but it's very interesting for Domino apps.